# How to assign marks to spatstat objects within loops / apply commands?

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

Some of spatstat functions, such as [`crossing.psp`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/crossing.psp) do not allow to assign marks within the function. I am making a complicated function with for loops and lapply commands, which calls for marks in `ppp` and `psp` objects. I am experiencing problems when trying to assign [marks](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/marks) to these objects when I use `get()` functions. Typically I would use `assign` function in these cases, but cannot get it to work. Here is an example:

```
library(spatstat)

win <- owin(c(0,1), c(0,1))
p1 <- ppp(0.1, 0.3, window = win)
p2 <- ppp(0.2, 0.4, window = win)
p3 <- ppp(0.4, 0.7, window = win)

points <- c("p1", "p2", "p3")
```

For those who are not familiar with the package, `marks` works followingly:

```
marks(p1) <- "p1"
```

What I want to do is (or something similar, which gives the desired result):

```
for(i in length(points)){
marks(get(points[i])) <- points[i]}
```

This, of course, does not work because I am using the assignment operator for `get` function. If I try `assign` function, I get an error

```
for(i in 1:length(points)) assign(marks(get(points[i])), points[i]) 

#Error in assign(marks(get(points[i])), points[i]) : 
#  invalid first argument

# Or following also gives the same error:

for(i in 1:length(points)) assign(x = marks, value = points[i], envir =  get(points[i]))
```

I have also tried:

```
setmarks(mget(points), points)
sapply(seq_along(points), function(i) marks(get(points[i])) <- points[i])
```

**How can I assign marks to spatspat objects within loops or using apply commands?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
for(i in points) {
    assign(i, do.call(`marks<-`, list(x=as.symbol(i), value=i)))
}

## Check a point patter to see that it works
marks(p3)
# [1] "p3"
```

If the need for a pair of nested function calls (the inner one to `marks<-()` and the outer one to `assign()`) seems mysterious, have a look at the ["subset assignment" section of R-lang](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment).

Comment: This piece of code contains some incredibly neat tricks for me (I never thought of directly placing the object name in the loop using `i` for instance). Thanks! I guess I´d manage to figure it out, but how would you do the same with `sapply`/`lapply`?